# Matlab GUI: referencing an existing object handle using a variable

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am currently working on my matlab final project for school. I consider myself fairly knowledgeable and proficient when it comes to programming.. but Matlab simply has TOO many oddities.

> ***The fundamental question*** *(realized this after finding the answer)!* How can I use a variable in a call to a gui handle object
>   without the name of the variable being used instead of the value?
>
> *In other words:* **Use a variable in a field name** (If I had known it was this simple I wouldn't of asked)

*My project* is building a simple rendition of the age old 'Battleship' game.

**My issue**: I currently 5 objects (axes) for the ship pieces. They are selected one at a time to be moved into another location(the grid). *I am able to* use the **setpixelposition** to move each object after a **button** click.

Right now under the button click, I have something like this

```
function btnPlaceShip_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

    %Store the current selected ship(passed from an onclick to a label) 
    ship = get(handles.lblSelectedShip,'string');

    %I have tried everything I could think of, but basically I want to achieve the
    %following

    setpixelposition(handles.ship, [0 250 50 250]) 
    %where the variable 'ship' contains the name of the object.
```

In other words, the *var* **ship** = 'shipAircraftCarrier', and..

```
    setpixelposition(handles.shipAircraftCarrier, [0 250 50 250])
```

**works!**(sets the position of the specific ship indicated). Using the variable **ship**, however, matlab takes the string literally and not for its value. It would be extremely convenient to use the variable instead!

If anyone have any solutions, I would be grateful. I have scoured the web but perhaps I am missing some fundamental understanding of the Matlab GUI stuff - The matlab help documents are very non-descriptive and are not of much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others use [dynamic fieldnames](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br1v5cc-1.html). Whilst not having the code to test it I believe that simply putting brackets around the **ship** will substitute the string in to the structure name, thus

```
setpixelposition(handles.(ship), [0 250 50 250])
```

Try to avoid the use of eval() if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this shortly. Before I saw this was answered, I had been trying various things all day! But I learned a lot - I am finally understanding how matlab is organizing all this gui stuff! I think everything was confusing because I did not understand the automatically generated code and It took a while to grasp it (i.e I now realize that 'handles' is simply a structure array!)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `eval` function, but you need to be careful about string injections:

```
setpixelposition(eval(strcat('handles.',ship)), [0 250 50 250])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would try this but other users mentioned I can just put the variable in parenthesis, like: setpixelposition(**handles.(ship)**, position) which is shorter. I don't think I need to worry about string injection in my matlab script, especially since this variable is not inputted via input box, but rather gui selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic fieldnames](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/20/advanced-matlab-dynamic-field-names/) or [getfield](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/getfield.html). Field indexing using identifiers vs strings is quite similar in Matlab `structs` and Javascript `objects`.

Matlab:

```
fromId = handles.shipAircraftCarrier; %identifier
fromString = handles.('shipAircraftCarrier'); %string
```

Javascript:

```
var fromId = handles.shipAircraftCarrier; //identifier
var fromString = handles["shipAircraftCarrier"]; //string
```

Comment: Thanks! the variable **shipTag** is a string variable that is equal to the tag of the ship. I will try using: **handles.(shipTag)** instead of handles.shipTag